# Ideas for application layout using angularJS

Tags: javascript, html5

I am converting a classic asp application that displays the status of any number of applications, can be one, can be 10+. I am using angularJS for the front end and restful web service for back end.

[image]

Up    - it contains the number of applications without issues
Down  - it contains the number of applications with issues
Other - Can be that the application is under maintenance no issue

When the StatusLine link gets clicked, the user gets taken to a info page providing the list and details of the outage of the specific application(s). There is also web form that allows the user to perform CRUD operations. The layout for the info page and the CRUD form I have it already completed.

I would like to ask for creative advice on how to improve the current layout of the design shown on the screen shot so that it stands out more.

An idea I had in mind, was to instead that using words like: Up, Down, Other, I could use font-awesome and display icons that indicate an application is Up, Down, or Other.

May be someone on this forum could share an idea, or two, that would be great. Or maybe there are some good examples online that I have not been able to find yet.

This is a simple design, not complex at all.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: This is pretty open. Without context and some solid UX question relating to it, I'm afraid your question doesn't fit the UX.SE model very well.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE. I don't think there's enough context provided right now for a proper answer. Can you show us what the current layout you have looks like? Either a screenshot or a wireframe would help. What does "up" "down" "other" mean?

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for the making it so abstract. I hope after having edited, it offers more visibility of what I need to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification. Call me dense, but I'm still not sure what the number besides the each status mean. e.g. "Up: 1" does 1 mean up for 1 min or 1 hour? Or is it like a boolean flag for true? Instead of asking "how to make it stand out more" a better question may be "how to make it easier to understand and provide info that's meaningful to the user". e.g. Does the user care that the app is currently up more or how long it's been up for? or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for a way to indicate the status of your application? There are a decent number of examples we can look to in the wild:

- [GitHub](https://status.github.com/)
- [Reddit](http://www.redditstatus.com/)
- [Xbox Live](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-live-status)

And commonly seen on GitHub for indicating the status of a given *codebase*: [SO Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13546097/how-do-show-my-tests-passing-failing-in-github)

So... These are just examples. The answer varies depending on *how many* "statuses" you would like to indicate, how much information you want your users to have access to (and how much do they even care for?), etc.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the examples. There are three type of statuses only. Users don't really care much about the details, just if the app is up or down or under maintenance.